# Client authorization issue with IdentityServer v4.1.2

Tags: authentication, authorization, identityserver4, openid

I built an IdentityServer4 project with version 4.1.2 and using Visual Studio 2019. I also built an MVC client project. MVC client is configured using code authorization flow.

When testing them in debugging mode, I got the following error messages:

```
"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1","title":"Data is Null
```

The authentication and authorization Uri is (decoded):

```
https://localhost:44326/connect/authorize?client_id=gyceY9JNAHqincYvSLbD&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44355/signin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid profile stock_api&code_challenge=ZVfXcplelSN1gxJSiyoSFe2Kov0rUcWr171QvJPTSOM&code_challenge_method=S256&
response_mode=form_post&nonce=637641439392636048.Y2I0NjE2NTAtMjJiMy00ZjAzLThiMmQtMGI3ZDA3MmYxOTkyNTc3MmQxNWEtYTJhMi00OGFiLTlkZmYtYjM3NWVjMzdkNGE5&state=CfDJ8OBuz55W8hVBm6ICBRA_m8EdrMfeMB5C_ywS1lxgvHC7RObH1V99WEt-1cZEV_7e097jhEti62beizRqupgho7lWCtj2IzMmZd-5Teumy19Erzq4I5W3xao6KzDUrzWYbIJrVowof6JmAdtUkS88JGiW_t48GG6EsmE9852i-A0NiL6qpgar8dE-hUh10oyxFkIDCFlvd-EJVtvPJ1rw_8TtA3L9sYbmxrR0n1JsfX2_o43jKbQP23aXDWf-JOmK3kabm31HpTQFHYaS4hKCldgt1h2pVXSUPHRy55quD_FRyrH-DjBiXHV-XC1mGR9tjf2J3ESWpg9bIOm2y99xYug4QFhJMzzHuVIS90anEavAcYMjcUa38xETxfpct5xqg&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.12.0.0
```

It looks I missed "Data" but I don't know what this 'Data' is and how to provide?

Comment: what does the IdentityServer logs say?

Comment: Can you provide the startup.cs of IdentityServer and the client?